# How to render HTML elements in different orders when in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row proadjuster">
  <div class="col-lg-5 propadder"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-7 pro2"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make sure `col-lg-7` displays first when in mobile view?

Comment: I recon you need to use media queries and hide the `col-lg-5 propadder` div above the `col-lg-7` to make it appear first.

Comment: Updated formatting, title and tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean like to col-lg-7 to switch position with col-lg-5, than you can make it like this

```
.row {
display: flex;
}

@media screen only and (max-width: 767px) {
.col-lg-7 {
order: 1; 
}
.col-lg-5 {
order: 2;
}
}
```